# SQL Match Contact Ids with Many Tag Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I seem to have got myself in a pickle, One table three columns, forget the Id column. I add a `tagId` to a `contactId`, so one `contactId` can have many `TagId's`

I need to select just `contactId's` that match my IN `TagId's` e.g.

-- The Table --
Id    ContactId    TagId
3136    2562    4
3137    2585    4
3139    2772    4
4543    2117    150
4882    2562    150
4903    2585    150
5067    2772    150
5229    2804    150
5241    2808    150
5244    2809    150
5247    2810    150
5250    2811    150
5457    2085    4

-- The SQL MSSQL 2005 --

```
SELECT [Id],[ContactId],[TagId]
FROM [search-contacts].[dbo].[ContactTagsGrouping]
WHERE ContactId IN (2085,2804,2808,2809,2810,2117,2811,2772,2562,2585) 
  AND TagId IN (150,4)
```

Thanks in advance, this is only a small sample of data, I have a couple of hundred rows, and the `TagId` IN () can have many `TagId's` selected.

In the above SQL, I should only see three `ContactId` records that match both 150 and 4 e.g.

ContactId
2772
2562
2585

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregation to match a given `ContactId` to a set of `TagId`:

```
SELECT [ContactId]
  FROM [search-contacts].[dbo].[ContactTagsGrouping]
  WHERE ContactId IN (2085,2804,2808,2809,2810,2117,2811,2772,2562,2585) 
    AND TagId IN (150,4)
group by ContactId
having count(distinct TagId)=2 /* 2 is the number of tags in the TagId in() */
```

If you have a unique index/constraint on `ContactId, TagId` then you can skip the `distinct` in `count(distinct TagId)` to remove any overhead incurred from a sort operator.

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RUF13404

returns:

```
+-----------+
| ContactId |
+-----------+
|      2562 |
|      2585 |
|      2772 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank's SqlZim, the only thing, the above TagId means 150 is Consultants, and 4 is Aberdeen, so someone may select a division of accounts which would change the TagId from 150,4,113. I guess I could also do a TagId count that way having count would then match the selected TagId's, I will try that, and again SqlZim thanks for your help,

Comment: Got it thanks, Zim, I just did a count on the TagId's and added that to your Having statement, all good now and thanks again.

SELECT [Id],[Name],[PhoneNo],[Email]
  FROM [search-contacts].[dbo].[Contacts] c INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT [ContactId]
  FROM [search-contacts].[dbo].[ContactTagsGrouping]
  WHERE TagId IN (113,150,4,0)
group by ContactId
having count(distinct TagId)=(SELECT COUNT([Id]) FROM [search-contacts].[dbo].[Tags] where Id IN (113,150,4,0))
) st ON c.Id = st.[ContactId]